# WebDriver and ChromeDriver: Unable to fix org/json/JSONException error

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am new to using Selenium WebDriver. I am trying to use ChromeDriver, and the following is my code:

```
public class WebScraper  {
    public WebScraper() {

    }

    public WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    public void openTestSite() {
        driver.navigate().to("https://google.com");
    }


    public void enter(String word) {

         WebElement query_editbox = 
         driver.findElement(By.id("query")); 
         query_editbox.sendKeys(word);
         query_editbox.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);

    }

//    public void getText()  {
//        //List<WebElement> searchResults = 
//        driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='mid']/div")); 
//        // Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new 
//        OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("status.txt"), 
//        "utf-8"));
//        //int[] index = {0};
//
//    WebElement result=driver.findElement(By.id("mid"));
//    System.out.println(result.getText());
//}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver");        
    System.out.println("Hello");

    WebScraper webScraper = new WebScraper();
    webSrcapper.openTestSite();
    webSrcapper.enter("avoir");
    //webSrcapper.getText();
    System.out.println("Hello");

}
}
```

I am receiving the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONException
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.init(RemoteWebDriver.java:110)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:92)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:144)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:86)
    at WebScraper.<init>(WebScraper.java:15)
    at WebScraper.main(WebScraper.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 6 more
```

Can someone please help me resolve this and tell me why I am receiving this error in the first place?

Thanks!

Comment: Selenium version?

Comment: Hi @DebanjanB, I am using the latest version of Selenium, so I don't think that should be the problem.

Comment: Can you be specific with the **version number** and if _selenium-java_ client kits or _selenium-server-standalone.jar_ or _maven/gradle dependency_?

Answer (score 0):

The error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONException

is because it missing dependency `org.json` add this https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20180813

Comment: Hi @ewwink, Thank you so much for your response! I have downloaded this dependency now, but do I need to import it using an official statement? Thanks, once again!

Comment: no, just put it in same place with selenium-server.jar

Comment: Ok, thank you so much! The issue seems to have been the selenium and chromedriver versions not corresponding.